# Creating a length zero cython array

Tags: python, cython

I would like to create a zero length array in Cython:

```
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

arr = cvarray(shape=(0,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i")
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid shape in axis 0: 0.
```

Is there a reason why I can't create a zero length array? Numpy allows zero length arrays, but I'm trying to avoid it, as I only want to use C functions in my code.

---

In response to hpaulj's question; here is an example use-case where I need it. The example fails when the input array `arr` is of length 1. I would prefer to return an empty array, instead of a None object. As I would like the return type to be consistent.

```
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cpdef delete(int[:] arr, int obj):
    cdef:
        int[:] result
        int j, i

    result = cvarray(shape=(len(arr)-1,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i")
    j = 0
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        if i==obj:
            j+=1
        result[i] = arr[j]
        j+=1
    return result
```

Comment: What's the purpose of such an array?  In `numpy` a (0,) shape array can only be indexed with an empty tuple, e.g. `x[()]`.  0d is a logical extension of 1d and 2d etc, but is rather limited in use.  Usually we only see it when wrapping a Python object in a single element, 0d, object dtype array.

Comment: I'm iterating over a generated array of data. If they array of data is empty then it will have zero length.

Comment: @hpaulj I expanded the question with more details in response to your question.

Comment: I guess, given this check https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L151, there is no official way for it. As for reasons - I don't know...

Comment: If you look at the code generated by `cvarray`, there's a bit of setting up dictionaries and tuples, then `__Pyx_PyObject_Call(((PyObject *)__pyx_array_type), __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_t_1)` - it really isn't optimised C code anyway

Answer (score 0):

To pre-empt myself, here's the tl;dr:

1. Declare your array with whatever shape and whatever dims,
2. Return a slice of the array terminating at index 0, i.e.:

```py
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cdef int[:] DoStuff( int[:] arr ):

    cdef int arrLen = arr.shape[0]
    if arrLen==0:
        return cvarray( shape=(1,), sizeof( int ), 'i' )[:0]
    
    #After this check, you can now proceed assuming arrLen > 0

    cdef int[:] result = cvarray( shape=(arrLen,), sizeof( int ), 'i' )
    ...

cdef int[:] stuffDone = DoStuff( arr = someEmptyThing )
print( stuffDone.shape[0] ) # -> 0
```

This is nice because it works with any number of dims. Though for n dims, you'll probably want to change that [:0] slice to [:0,:0,...] (n times), or you end up with weird stuff like stuffDone.shape = [0, 420, 69...]. This is obviously nonsensical, but I'm not actually sure that it matters, though I don't know if it confuses mem allocation.

I happen to have run into this problem too. It's surprising to me that the use of such a thing isn't obvious: very often we have a function that needs to populate an array based on some conditions, without knowing in advance whether those conditions will be satisfied, and thus, whether the array will contain any data. Building some convoluted function to determine in advance whether the array will contain anything is cumbersome and inefficient, as it often involves looping over the data twice (once for the count, twice to actually build the array) and writing a bunch of ugly extra code to handle the one single case where the result variable can't be of type cvarray. Thus being able to have a size 0 array is nice. Not that the use really matters anyway - we're here to answer HOW to do things, not interrogate people about WHY they want to do them and express our disapproval :)