# Missing numpy attribute when using Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a very simply cython module called `empty_test.pyx`:

```
cimport numpy as cnp


cpdef return_empty():
    return cnp.empty(0, dtype=np.int32)
```

When I try to run `return_empty` I get this error:

```
empty_test.pyx:5:14: cimported module has no attribute 'empty'
```

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy as np
setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(['empty_test.pyx'],
    ),
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
)
```

I'm aware that I could try `import numpy as np` instead of `cimport numpy as np`, but I'm trying to use C versions of the numpy code.

Comment: There is a misconception. cimport does not give you the same library as import, just in c. It gives you access to predefined types. This tutorial may be helpful for getting a deeper understanding of the interplay of types and function: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inorder to achieve that, you have to access numpy's C-API directly, which is at least partly wrapped by Cython. In your case you need [`PyArray_SimpleNew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNew), which is already [cimported with numpy](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/34bc649fa15776c412e3a3e28454c439e51b972a/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L553).

Thus, your function becomes:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as cnp

cnp.import_array()  # needed to initialize numpy-API

cpdef return_empty():
    cdef cnp.npy_intp dim = 0
    return cnp.PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &dim, cnp.NPY_INT32)
```

And now:

```
>>> return_empty()
array([], dtype=int32)
```

Obviously, there is still some Python overhead because of the reference-counting but it is much less, as when using `np.empty()`:

```
>>> %timeit return_empty()   
159 ns ± 2.81 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit return_empty_py
751 ns ± 8.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

Using `PyArray_SimpleNew` is also faster (about 3 times) than using Cython's `array` (as considered [by you in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53026747/5769463)):

```
%%cython
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

# shape=(0,) doesn't work
cpdef create_almost_empty_carray():
    return cvarray(shape=(1,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i")
```

and thus:

```
>>> %timeit create_almost_empty_carray()
435 ns ± 5.85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

Listing of used function `return_empty_py`:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np

cpdef return_empty_py():
    return np.empty(0, np.int32)
```