# Cython: Effectively using Numpy in Pure Python Mode

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am fairly new to using Cython and I am interested in using the "Pure Python" mode.

The work that I am doing right now uses numpy extensively and knowing that there is a C api for numpy, I was excited to see what it could do.

As a small test, I put together two small test files, `test.py` and `test.pxd`. Their content is as follows:

test.py:

```
import cython
import numpy as np

@cython.locals(array=np.ndarray)
@cython.returns(np.ndarray)
def test(array):
    return np.cumsum(array)

test_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
test(test_array)
```

test.pxd:

```
# cython: language_level=3
cimport numpy as np

cdef np.ndarray test(np.ndarray array)
```

I then compiled these files with `cython -a test.py` with the hopes that I would see little to no python interaction when calling np.cumsum(). However when I inspected the generated HTML file, I found the following:

[image]

From this, it appears that my call to np.cumsum heavily interacts with python, which is something that feels counter-intuitive. My expectation, since I (should) be using the cimported numpy, is that there should be very little python interaction.

My question is "is my intuition correct?". Have I set something up incorrectly with my files that is not allowing the cimported numpy to actually be used for the function call, and that is why I am still seeing so much yellow? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You are using imported and not the cimported functionality. Use „cimport numpy as cnp“ to see the difference.

Comment: After doing some reading I don't think this is the solution @ead and seems to lead to compile errors: 'cimported module has no attribute "cumsum"'. Following the post below, it seems that cimport only gives you access to the predefined types, not the c version of numpy functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026820/missing-numpy-attribute-when-using-cython

Comment: It was only an explanation, why you see python overhead, not a way to speed-up things. If cumsum has no c-api version, you will have to pay this overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the types as `np.ndarray` mainly improves one thing: it makes indexing them to get single values significantly faster. Almost everything else remains the same speed.

`np.cumsum` (and any other Numpy function) is called through the standard Python mechanism and runs at exactly the same speed (internally of course it's implemented in C and should be quite quick). Mathematical operator (such add `+, -, *, etc.`) are also called through Python and remain the same speed.

In reality your wrapping probably makes it slower - it adds an unnecessary type-check (to make sure that the array is an `np.ndarray`) and an extra layer of indirection.

There is nothing to be gained through typing here.

Comment: I can understand that typing doesn't really gain me anything here (thank you for your answer btw!). What is now less clear to me is the purpose of the cimported version of numpy. Since numpy is primarily written in C, my thought is that the cimported version of numpy aimed to reduce the amount of python interaction rather than changing anything in numpy's backend. If this isn't the case, what does cimporting actually give us?

Comment: The purpose is to let you do `arr[x]` (index a single element) and for that to be quick. In a loop that can be a massive speed gain. It mainly helps for algorithms that can't easily be vectorized

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've done a bit more digging and found the documentation linked below. The comments in the code snippits are especially helpful and follow what you are saying to a T.

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html